# Indic font(Kannada) is not rendering properly in Android ICS

Tags: android

I am trying to get the kannada font support for Android ICS. I rooted my Xperia Neo L phone which is running Android ICS 4.0.4 and installed Kannada font (Lohit-Kannada.ttf). I have also included the Lohit-Kannada font as family-set in fallback_fonts.xml in the framework. After that, I am able to see the kannada fonts render in browser but the complex script is not supported. Glyphs are not rendered in proper way, though it is just readable. Other indic languages like Tamil, Hindi, Bengali etc renders perfectly but my language is not rendering properly. Someone suggested me to go thru this blog. http://androidandsandu.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-add-indian-languages-to-android.html
But i'm not able to find out where to make those file changes. I mean where is that lohit-fonts directory, where is the android.mk file? I'm not able to find those folders or those files in my phone. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided explains how to change the source code of a custom Android image to do what you want:

> Prerequisites :
>   ICS (4.0.3) AOSP source code
>   ...

so I guess it is not possible without building your own custom ROM.